# Azure QuotaExceededException

Tags: exception, azure

When sending a notifications to a notificationhub I receive the following exception:

> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QuotaExceededException: The remote
>   server returned an error <403> Forbidden. The maximum number of
>   Notification operations has been reached or exceeeded. Actual:33360,
>   Max allowed: 33000..TrackingID55ccd1f7a791-4047-96fd-0d0be2278ff7_g7

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Isn't that specific enough: "Actual:33360, Max allowed: 33000".

Comment: Is there something stopping you performing fewer then notification 33,000 operations?

Comment: The thing is, successful notifications have never exceeded 8600 and Messages never exceeded 41 and registration operations 333. So my question is what are the other operations that could be generating this exception?

Comment: I just send a handful of notifications and got the same exception. I have however made a lot of device registrations and updates (not actually sending something), so I'm convinced all operations you do against the HubClient counts against the quota.

Comment: @user2320351 have you got it solved ?

Answer (score 2):

What you should keep in mind is that it appears that *all operations* (not only sending notifications) you do with the `NotificationHubClient` seems to add to your daily `Operations Quota`.

I have made the mistake of doing unnecessary registration updates whenever the client logs on to my API.
Device registrations are valid for 90 days, so I'll not have to make any updates unless the registration has/about to expire. (I do save the expire date, which you'll get from the RegistrationDescripton.ExpirationTime, in my user table in my server app for knowing when to do a registration update)

Comment: When you say not making any updates unless registration has/about to expire, does this include registering with notification hub with each app launch or user sign in?